# How to set Response Headers with Grails CacheHeaders Plugin?

Tags: html, grails, groovy, httprequest, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.4.4 with the [Cache Headers Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers).

Here is the tag I use:

```
  withCacheHeaders {
    etag {
      "${objectType}-${lastModifiedDateTime}-${width}-${objectId}".encodeAsSHA1()
    }
    delegate.lastModified {
      lastModifiedDate ?: 0
    }
    generate {

      response.setContentType(ImageService.getMimeTypeFromFileName(fullFileName))
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"${fullFileName}\"")
      response.setContentLength(imageBytes?.size())

      response.outputStream << imageBytes
    }        
  } // end withCacheHeaders
```

t works fine but it turns out that the response headers I set are not part of the response. They were perfectly set when I do not use the plugin.

Here are the headers which are set:

[image]

The headers which are not set are the one declared with:

```
response.setContentType(ImageService.getMimeTypeFromFileName(fullFileName))
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"${fullFileName}\"")
response.setContentLength(imageBytes?.size())
```

I.e., mime type, file name, content length.

**How to set Response Headers with Grails CacheHeaders Plugin?**

Comment: What response headers are not being set correctly? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why these headers do not get set is by design. Not design of the plugin but HTTP. According to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3) `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers should not be sent with HTTP response status of 304.